# Why am I getting this SyntaxError?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm pretty new in python and I'm getting this error and can't get rid of it. I read docs and tutorials but I just can't see where's the problem. Here's the error:

```
Caused by: SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input 'if'" , ('<iostream>', 107, 14, '              if b.getType() != Material.WATER:\n'))
```

Here's my code:

```
    removable = True
    ticker_vertical = 0.0
    ticker_horisontal = (random.random() * 2 * math.pi)
    l = sender.getLocation()
    b = l.getBlock()
    entity = l.getWorld().spawnFallingBlock(l, b.getType(), b.getData())
    if args[0] == "spawn":
       if l.getBlock().getType() != Material.AIR:
          entity.setMetadata("vortex", FixedMetadataValue(PyPlugin, "protected")
          if b.getType() != Material.WATER: #this is line which is causing error
             b.setType(Material.AIR)
          else:
              pass
       else:
           pass
       l = sender.getLocation()
       radius = math.sin(ticker_vertical * 2)
       v = Vector(radius * math.cos(horisontal), 0.5, radius * math.sin(horisontal))
       b1 = entity.getLocation().add(v.clone().normalize()).getBlock()
       if b1.getType() != Material.AIR:
          new_blocks.add(b.getLocation(), b.getType(), b.getData())
       entities = entity.getNearbyEntities(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
       for e in entities:
           if e.hasMetaData("vortex"):
             new_blocks.add(entity)
       entity.setVelocity(v)
       if ticker_vertical < 1.0:
          ticker_vertical += 0,05
    elif args[0] == "stop":
        entity.remove()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And `ticker_vertical += 0,05` also looks incorrect. `,` creates a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the preceding line; you are missing a `)` closing parenthesis:

```
entity.setMetadata("vortex", FixedMetadataValue(PyPlugin, "protected")
#                                              ^--- closes there ----^
#                 ^ --- open                           but no close --^
```

Further down you used a comma instead of a decimal point:

```
if ticker_vertical < 1.0:
    ticker_vertical += 0,05
```

You probably wanted:

```
if ticker_vertical < 1.0:
    ticker_vertical += 0.05
```

You can (and should) remove all the:

```
else:
    pass
```

lines, they do nothing whatsover and are not needed.

Comment: Oh, thanks a ton. I knew it's something stupid I couldn't see. About comma, that's just typo :D Thank you very much! :) I'll accept your answer as soon as I can (5 mins).

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on line 9:

```
entity.setMetadata("vortex", FixedMetadataValue(PyPlugin, "protected")
```

should be:

```
entity.setMetadata("vortex", FixedMetadataValue(PyPlugin, "protected"))
```